# web3py: How to interact with deployed contract abi

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, python, web3.py

I'm trying to interact with    a smart contract I deployed with truffle using web3py
 I can't figure out how to load the abi string into the web3py eth.contract function

`contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=...)`

How do I load my ABI [ ] interface into the above function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of web3py, the `abi` field accepts either of two types:

- a list of dictionaries, defining the ABI
- a string, that is the json-encoded version of the ABI

Answer (score 1):

Load the abi with json loads function :

```
import json
with open('Contract.abi') as json_file:
    myabi = json.load(json_file)
```